# C++ destruction point guarantee multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following simplified code at which while writing I thought was fine, but I have seem some random access violations.

Initially I thought as long as the arguments passed to async were on the stack, and not temporary variables, the code would be safe. I also thought that filename and extra data would destruct/considered not there at the brace where they leave scope.

It did some more research and read about the 'as if' principle that apparently compilers use for optimisation. I've often seen stack variables being optimised away in the debugger right after they have been used too.

My question here is basically, is it guaranteed that those stack variables will be around for the entire duration of the async function running. The .get() call on the future obviously synchronises the call before the two stack variables leave scope.

My current thinking is that it's not thread safe as the compiler can't see the variables being used after the call to the function, and therefore think it is safe to remove them. I can easily change the code to eliminate the problem (if there is one), but I really want to understand this.

The randomness of the AV, occurring more on some computers than others suggests it is a problem, and the scheduling order dictates whether this is a problem or not.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <future>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int write_some_file(const char * const filename, int * extra_result)
{
    std::ofstream fs;

    try {
        fs.open(filename);
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure e) {
        return 1;
    }

    fs << "Hello";

    *extra_result = 1;

    return 0;   
}

int main(void)
{

    std::string filename {"myffile.txt"};
    int extraResult = 0;

    auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, write_some_file, filename.c_str(), &extraResult);

    // Do some other work

    // ...

    int returnCode = result.get();

    std::cout << returnCode << std::endl;
    std::cout << extraResult << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, your assumptions are incorrect. Since the address of the variable is taken, compiler can't optimize it away. In fact, the code as posted is safe.

Comment: Side note: std::streams do not throw an exception, unless enabled explicitly.

Comment: Ok Thanks. SergeyA the address of the string isn't taken. A function returns an address pointing to the c string.

Comment: I ran your program a few hundred thousand times, never had a crash or error. Nothing it it looks wrong to me, either. Is this very code what's crashing, or does it need "Do some other work"?

Comment: Thanks for that. Yea it does other work, however if i change it to be single threaded no crash.

Comment: @PhilWilliams: Then the other work is causing the problem. Can you include that here? Or at least with fake function calls (dummy implementations).